# Explanation on passed procedure execution

Tags: lambda, scheme, lisp, sicp

In SICP lecture 2a, I'm confused on `(average (f x) x)`. Can it not just be `(average f x)`. Doesn't `f` mean the `lambda` of `(/ x y)` already? Why do I need `(average (f x) x)`?  Could someone help me out with the substitution method for this?

```
(define (sqrt x)
    (fixed-point
        (average-damp (λ (y) (/ x y)))
        1))

(define average-damp
    (λ (f)
        (λ (x) (average (f x) x))))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This snippet:

```
(average (f x) x)
```

Means a different thing than this:

```
(average (f) x)
```

For starters, `f` is a *function* that expects a single parameter, which in this case must be `x`, hence we say `(f x)` . If you write `(f)` you're trying to call `f` with no parameters, resulting in an error. Substituting in `average-damp` after calling it with a value for the `f` parameter we discover that it returns *another* `lambda`, which is:

```
(λ (x)
  (average ((λ (y) (/ x y)) x) x))
```

As you can see, in this expression `((λ (y) (/ x y)) x)`, `x` is passed as a parameter to `(λ (y) (/ x y)) x)` (which was `f`), and `x` binds to the `y` parameter. Don't get confused! because now we have:

```
(/ x x)
```

But the first `x` at this point is not a variable, it's the *value* that was captured in a closure when calling `sqrt`, whereas the second `x` is the parameter in the `lambda` that we just returned, and is still unbound until the point where it gets called, presumably in `fixed-point`.

Comment: so anytime i want to run a lamda expression that is a formal parameter i need to  do (lamdba-name paramater)?

Comment: @runners3431 yes, every time you need to _execute_ a `lambda` (it doesn't matter if it's a formal parameter or not) you have to pass the expected arguments. But it depends on the `lambda` expression, if it doesn't have parameters then it's ok to call it like this `(f)` - but if it has one, two, etc. parameters _and_ you need to invoke it, then the correct number of parameters must be provided.

Comment: @runners3431 There exist `lambda`s with variable number of arguments, and with optional arguments. I won't get into the details, but the key point is: a `lambda` is like any other procedure (except that it doesn't have a name), and you have to call it with the appropriate arguments

Comment: "a lambda is like any other procedure (except that it doesn't have a name" — Do any procedures have names? No.  When you have a form like `(<form> ...)`, you evaluate `<form>`, and the value should be a procedure.  The value of a variable can be a procedure (e.g., if you've done (define (foo …) …)` or `(let ((foo (lambda …`, and the value of `(lambda …)` is a procedure.

Comment: @JoshuaTaylor What I meant to explain is that a lambda is an anonymous procedure